# How to extract value from href in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-crawler

1. Hi developer. I am facing a problem in extracting a href value in python.
2. I have a button there after clicking on "view Answer" it take me a next link I want to extract that data which is present in that link.

   ```
   <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-12">
   <a href="https://www.marham.pk/forum/thread/4471/i-need-a-good-orthopedic- dr">
   <div class="hover-div">
   <h2 itemprop="name">i need a good Orthopedic dr</h2>

   </div>
   </a>
   <div class="thread-details">
   <a href="https://www.marham.pk/forum/thread/4471/i-need-a-good-orthopedic-dr">
   <p class="pull-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> View Answers (<span itemprop="answerCount">1</span>) </p>
           </a>
   </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. I need to extract this href tag.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Data Scraping In Python.
Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.

> import bs4 as bs
>
> import urllib.request
>
> sauce = urllib.request.urlopen("Your URL WILL GO HERE").read()
>
> soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'html5lib')
>
> print(soup)

Comment: If You Didn't Understand The Answer Comment It below.And clarify your question.
Whether you want that link extract from html tag or you want to extract the data from that link.

Comment: i want to extract data from that href

Comment: Then You Have To Use BeatifulSoup Library Of Python.
It will Extract the data from given Link.
If any help needed comment below.

Comment: yes i know this but how?? i want to extract the value which is on that href means after clicking this link that value which is shown on that address

Comment: Yeah I Done Some Changes In My Post. I Added Some Code Give A Try

Comment: sorry you don't understand what i am saying can i ping you on skype??

Comment: Ping me on LinkedIn Search For Munaf Hajir